# Krishna's Gandhara wife?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, krishna, marriage, swayamvar

"*Of eyes like the lotus petals, and endued with great bravery, Krishna, vanquishing all the kings at a self-choice, bore away the daughter of the king of the Gandharas.*"

SECTION XI  Dronabhisheka parva, Mahabharata

Who is this wife of Krishna ? Is she mentioned in the Puranas ?